# SqlConnection command throws no Exception on delete

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, unit-testing

I am working on Unit Tests and i made a test that tests the following method:

> public void DeleteTransport(int id)
>
> ```
>    {
>        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(SQL_CONN);
>        try
>        {
>            sqlConnection.Open();
>            SqlCommand dbCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
>            dbCommand.CommandText = string.Format("DELETE FROM dbo.Transports WHERE ID={0}", id);
>            SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(dbCommand);
>
>            var ds = new DataSet("Transports");
>            dap.Fill(ds);
>        }
>        finally
>        {
>            sqlConnection.Close();
>        }
>    }
> ```

In the Unit Test, I give a not existing id as parameter, but the method doesnt throws an SqlException.

How to throw an Exception if the id doesnt exists?

I am using:

- Visual Studio 2012
- TFS
- Sql Server 2008

Comment: There is no exception since there is no faulty situation. After the statement is executed there is no  record in Transports with the requested ID.

Comment: Why are you using a DataSet and a SqlDataAdapter for this in the first place? Why not just call ExecuteNonQuery and see what the result is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wouldn't throw an exception, it would simply update 0 rows.

You could check how many rows were affected by using `ExecuteNonQuery()` and if they are equal to 0, you could throw an Exception (Which would be computionally expensive) but would achieve what you expect.

You could also rewrite the unit test to Assert that the rows affected is greater than 0.

Comment: Or he could check before the delete instructions, if the id exists, and then create an exception if not.(don't know if it's more expensive that your suggestion).

Comment: thanks for the usefull suggestions! _ExecuteNonQuery_ works much better indeed!